# Should I seal bathroom ceiling and wall tiles?

Tags: bathroom, tile, bathtub

The previous owner put tiles around the bathtub like ceiling and side walls. I wonder if I need to seal these tiles in order to protect them from the water? Will it increase its lifespan?

Comment: Are they glazed tile and is the grout already sealed?  any pics??

Comment: Well I will send a picture once I get to the home but I don't think they are sealed. Well honestly I am not even sure how I can know if it is sealed or not. If I remember correctly, if the tile beats up the water, it is sealed.

Comment: glazed tile does not need to be sealed, but grout should be and is really easy to do and very inexpensive.